# What's the correct way to manage an often-duplicated object in your model?

Tags: uv, objects

I'm making a machine of sorts, and there's this one hinge object that I'm basically using over and over again, for every joint.

It seems a waste to, for example, make a different UV map for each of these. Is there a good way to just use the exact same object in multiple different places on a model? Ideally this process would be non-destructive, so I can edit the "root" object and have the edit propagate to every instance of this hinge.

Comment: @RobinBetts is there a better term than 'instancing', now that Blender is using 'instancing' to refer to creating instances on the vertices or faces of an object?

Comment: @Marty Oops, you're right.. Blender calls it [Duplicate Linked](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/scene_layout/object/editing/duplicate_linked.html).. It's called 'instancing' everywhere else I've been :) I suppose you have to call one of those a 'Linked Duplicate'?

Comment: ..@Locust  .. the by-hand way is Alt-D. You can also Ctrl-L link existing objects to the active object to make them share the same mesh-data